# How to plot many graphs with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a plot from 51 graphs. And I want to fit the graphs into 3 columns and 17 rows, so I will get graphs with decent size.  Results from following code squeezed the graphs vertically. I would appreciate if someone could help resolve this.

```
    p<-ggplot(results, aes(x=lidar, y=zval, col=meas)) + 
  geom_violin(aes(x=lidar, y=zval, group=lidar, fill=lidar), inherit.aes = FALSE)+  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightblue", "lightgreen"))+
  geom_jitter(aes(alpha=signif, shape=meas), size=3, color="black") + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=1:nlevels(as.factor(results$meas))) +
  facet_wrap(~species, ncol=3, drop = FALSE) + geom_abline(intercept = 1.96, slope = 0, col="orange")+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 13, margin = margin()), axis.title = element_text(size=35,face="bold"),
        axis.text=element_text(size=25), legend.text = element_text(size=25), legend.title = element_text(size=25))+
  labs(y = "Z value", x="Sensors", shape="Metrics")+guides(alpha=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: The height of the plot is determined by the plotting  device. The only way to have this plot look nice is to adjust the height when you save or export your plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot @stefan, adjusting the height when saving did the job.

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove the cramped text along Y axis (0,2,4,6).

```
+theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

I believe that the graph would still be meaningful